# Зачем использовать $emit во Vue если можно просто передать метод в пропсах?

Tags: vue.js

Объясните мне пожалуйста, зачем мне нужно использовать $emit во VUE, писать кучу усложняющего кода, если я просто могу написать метод меняющий состояние родительского компонента и передать его в пропсах в дочерний компонент?

Eсли я использую $emit(это 6 действий и куча кода):

- я должен создать метод меняющий состояние в родителе

  ```
  toggleFavoriteStatus(friendId) {
    const identifiedFriend = this.friends.find((friend) => 
    friend.id===friendId);
    identifiedFriend.isFavorite = !identifiedFriend.isFavorite;
  },
  ```
- передать его в событие в дочерний компонент шаблоне родителя

  ```
  <friend-contact
    v-for="friend in friends"
    :id="friend.id"
    @toggle-favorite="toggleFavoriteStatus">
  </friend-contact>
  ```
- создать метод в дочернем компоненте
- подписать его через $emit в этом методе

  ```
  methods: {
    toggleIsFavorite() {
      this.$emit("toggle-favorite", this.id);
    },
  },
  ```
- вызвать его в шаблоне дочернего компонента

  ```
  <button @click="toggleIsFavorite">Is Favorite</button>
  ```
- еще и экспортировать в поле emits

  ```
  emits:["toggle-favorite"]
  ```

Если я просто передаю метод в пропсах (4 действия и все понятно и наглядно)

- я делаю метод меняющий состояние в родителе

  ```
  toggleFavoriteStatus(id) {
    const identifiedFriend = this.friends.find((friend) => friend.id === id);
    identifiedFriend.isFavorite = !identifiedFriend.isFavorite;
  },
  ```
- передаю его в пропсах в дочерний шаблон

  ```
  <friend-contact
    v-for="friend in friends"
    :id="friend.id"
    :is-favorite="toggleFavoriteStatus">
  </friend-contact>
  ```
- принимаю его в пропсах в компоненте

  ```
  props: {
      id: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
      },
      isFaforite: {
        type: Function,
        required: true,
      },
    },
  ```
- и просто вызываю по клику в шаблоне передав нужные данные как агрумент функции

  ```
  <button @click="isFavorite(id)">Favorite</button>
  ```

Зачем мне все усложнять, если я могу сделать все проще и получить тот же результат? Может я чего то не понял?

Comment: Потому что у Вас событие может быть вызвано в зависимости от состояния. Не только по стандартным событиям типа клика или ховера. Кнопка на изменение фаворита если внутри, то Вы и не вызовете никак Ваш метод на изменение. Если снаружи - эмиты вам и не нужны.

Comment: Всё сильно зависит от изолированности компонентов. Если Вы будете несколько раз эти фавориты использовать - ну и будете везде логику однотипную плодить. Не по DRY это как-то...

Answer (score 0):

Судя по треду в междунарождной версии, это просто удобне для реализации библиотек, плюс имеется пара обобых кейсов:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/52677402/11568337

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]